# Getting Error: IsolatedStorage_Operation_ISFS while creating a file from silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am getting the IsolatedStorage_Operation_ISFS exception while try to Create Zip file in the Isolated Storage in MAC machine. Although this is working very well in windows. Please suggest any solution.

```
This is the error -System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException: [IsolatedStorage_Operation_ISFS]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.1.40728.00&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=IsolatedStorage_Operation_ISFS
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
   at Salient.SharpZipLib.Zip.IsolatedFastZip.ProcessFile(Object sender, ScanEventArgs e)
   at Salient.SharpZipLib.Core.IsolatedFileSystemScanner.OnProcessFile(String file)
   at Salient.SharpZipLib.Core.IsolatedFileSystemScanner.ScanDir(String directory, Boolean recurse)
   at Salient.SharpZipLib.Core.IsolatedFileSystemScanner.ScanDir(String directory, Boolean recurse)
   at Salient.SharpZipLib.Core.IsolatedFileSystemScanner.Scan(String directory, Boolean recurse)
   at Salient.SharpZipLib.Zip.IsolatedFastZip.CreateZip(Stream outputStream, String sourceDirectory, Boolean recurse, String fileFilter, String directoryFilter)
   at MediaTime.OfficeOpenHelper.SinglePlanExcelHelper.CreateZip(String zipFileName, String sourceDirectory, Boolean recurse, String fileFilter)
```

Comment: The same problem in Windows 10... in IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor as well.